# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir los atributos de un array de objetos que ingrese por pantalla? Si los tengo en un switch (java)

Tags: java, array

He intentado imprimir el *array* de objetos de varias formas sin ningún resultado positivo. La idea es que en un case ingrese los valores y en otro `case` los imprima, sin embargo no he logrado hacer que se impriman.

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int elegir,elija;// Estas son las variables del programa main
        int inte=0, inte2=0, n=0;
        Vehículos llamar= new Vehículos();//Aca empiezan los objetos
        Scanner entrar= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Código=0;// Estos son los constructores de la clase vehículos    
        String Marca="";
        String Tipo="";
        String Modelo="";
        int KM=0;
        String programa="";
        int boleano=0;

        do {              
        System.out.println("Bienvenido al concesionario Diego");
        System.out.println("Que desea hacer: \n"+ " 1. Agregar autos  \n"+ " 2. Mostrar autos\n");
        elegir= entrada.nextInt();

           switch(elegir){
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("Digite el número de registros que desea hacer");
                n= entrada.nextInt();
                Vehículos ccm[] = new Vehículos[n];               
                for(int i=0;i<ccm.length;i++)  {
                System.out.println("Ingresa el Código del vehículo");
                Código = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ingresa la Marca");
                Marca = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingresa el Tipo");
                Tipo = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingresa el Modelo");
                Modelo = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingresa el Kilometraje");
                KM = entrada.nextInt();
                ccm[i] = new Vehículos(Código, Marca, Tipo, Modelo, KM);
                }
                System.out.println("Acá va los registros");
                inte++;
                break;  
            }
            case 2://caso de registro de autos
            {
                 Vehículos ccm[] = new Vehículos[n];   
                if (inte>0){
                System.out.println("***********************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("********                           VEHÍCULOS                               ********");
                System.out.println("***********************************************************************************");
                for(int i=0;i<ccm.length;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("*"+ccm[i].getCódigo()+"*"+ccm[i].getMarca()+"*"+ccm[i].getTipo()+"*"+ccm[i].getModelo()+"*"+ccm[i].getKM()+"*");

                }//Problema__de__impresión
                else {
                    System.out.println("No tiene registros aún");
                }
                }

                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Desea finalizar el programa? presione S/N");
    programa = entrar.nextLine();
    programa = programa.toUpperCase();
        if (programa.equals("S")){
                    boleano=boleano+1;
                }
                System.out.println(""+boleano);      

        }while(boleano<1); 
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase vehículos:

```
public class Vehículos {

    private int Código;
    private String Marca;
    private String Tipo;
    private String Modelo;
    private int KM;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);    
    public Vehículos() {
        Código=0;
        Marca="";
        Tipo="";
        Modelo="";
        KM=0;  
    }
    public Vehículos(int a, String b, String c, String d, int f)
    {
        Código=a;
        Marca=b;
        Tipo=c;
        Modelo=d;
        KM=f;
    } 

    public int getCódigo() {
        return Código;
    }
    public void setCódigo(int Código) {
        this.Código = Código;
    }
    public String getMarca() {
        return Marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String Marca) {
        this.Marca = Marca;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return Tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String Tipo) {
        this.Tipo = Tipo;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return Modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String Modelo) {
        this.Modelo = Modelo;
    }

    public int getKM() {
        return KM;
    }

    public void setKM(int KM) {
        this.KM = KM;
    }

}
```

Al compilar me dice que la variable `n` del array de objetos está declarada 2 veces, pero si declaro el *array* de objetos en el `main` no me ingresa al `for` del caso 1.

Answer (score 1):

Para Java todos los case de un switch "son" como un solo grupo, por lo que no puedes declarar variables con el mismo nombre.

Lo que tienes que hacer es declararlas antes aunque no las inicialices.

```
Vehículos ccm[]
......
switch(elegir){
    case 1:
         .....
         ccm[] = new Vehículos[n];
         .....
         break;
    case 2:
         .....
         ccm[] = new Vehículos[n];
         .....
 }
```

Ahora, viendo tu codigo intuyo que lo que quieres hacer es que los autos registrados en el primer case se listen en el segundo. En ese caso NUNCA tienes que inicializar en el segundo case.

```
Vehículos ccm[]
......
switch(elegir){
    case 1:
         .....
         ccm[] = new Vehículos[n];
         .....
         break;
    case 2:
         .....
         // Aquí no hay que inicializar
         .....
 }
```

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias JDev, si exactamente lo que dices necesito que los autos se listen en el segundo. una pregunta en la parte de inicialización del primer case ¿el vector se inicializa como un objeto?, lo que sucede es que me da este mensaje not statement  ';' expected not a statement cannot find symbol                symbol: claas ccm              location JavaApplication2. Muchas

Comment: Si, falta un punto y coma al final de `Vehículos ccm[]`

Answer (score 1):

Perdona Diego que no me fijé bien en el código, te explico.

Aparte de lo de la identación que te han recomendado y lo cual es muy útil para tener el código ordenado te voy a dar un par de consejos que te ayudarán en el futuro.

- No poner acentos en los nombres de clases y atributos (puedes ponerlos en las Strings que saques por pantallas pero a nivel interno no es recomendable ya que algunas máquinas pueden no saberlos interpretar y hacer que no funcione tu código)
- Si no sabes de qué tamaño va a ser la array que vas a utilizar por que el tamaño lo dictamina el usuario por teclado no puedes usar una array estática (Vehiculos[] ccm) si no que tienes que utlizar una array dinámica (List ccm).
- En las clases no hace falta instanciar el Scanner, sólo donde lo vas a usar.
- Cuando haces con el Scanner un nextInt() solo recoge el contenido que has introducido pero no el /n (Enter) por lo que la Marca se introducía como un enter, esto se arregla poniendo scanner.nextLine() debajo de cada nextInt() que hagas.
- Recomendable insertar el ToString en las clases POJO para cuando quieras mostrarlas por pantalla ahorrarte el churro de código.

Son Tips que te pueden ayudar en el futuro. Te comparto el código que funciona con las módificaciones que te he comentado.

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int elegir,elija;// Estas son las variables del programa main
        int inte=0, inte2=0, n=0;
        Vehiculos llamar= new Vehiculos();//Aca empiezan los objetos
        Scanner entrar= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Código=0;// Estos son los constructores de la clase vehículos
        String Marca="";
        String Tipo="";
        String Modelo="";
        int KM=0;
        String programa="";
        int boleano=0;
        List<Vehiculos> ccm = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            System.out.println("Bienvenido al concesionario Diego");
            System.out.println("Que desea hacer: \n"+ " 1. Agregar autos  \n"+ " 2. Mostrar autos\n");
            elegir= entrada.nextInt();

            switch(elegir){
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("Digite el número de registros que desea hacer");
                    n= entrada.nextInt();

                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  {
                        System.out.println("Rellene la información del Vehículo " + (i+1));
                        System.out.println("Ingresa el Código del vehículo");
                        Código = entrada.nextInt();
                        entrada.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Ingresa la Marca");
                        Marca = entrada.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Ingresa el Tipo");
                        Tipo = entrada.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Ingresa el Modelo");
                        Modelo = entrada.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Ingresa el Kilometraje");
                        KM = entrada.nextInt();
                        ccm.add(new Vehiculos(Código, Marca, Tipo, Modelo, KM));
                    }
                    System.out.println("Acá va los registros");
                    inte++;
                    break;
                }
                case 2://caso de registro de autos
                {
                    if (inte>0) {
                        System.out.println("***********************************************************************************");
                        System.out.println("********                           VEHÍCULOS                               ********");
                        System.out.println("***********************************************************************************");
                        for (int i = 0; i < ccm.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println(ccm.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                            System.out.println("No tiene registros aún");
                    }
                 break;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Desea finalizar el programa? presione S/N");
            programa = entrar.nextLine();
            programa = programa.toUpperCase();
            if (programa.equals("S")){
                boleano=boleano+1;
            }
            System.out.println(""+boleano);

        }while(boleano<1);
    }
}
```

Y aquí la clase Vehiculo con el ToString

```
public class Vehiculos {

    private int Código;
    private String Marca;
    private String Tipo;
    private String Modelo;
    private int KM;
    public Vehiculos() {
        Código=0;
        Marca="";
        Tipo="";
        Modelo="";
        KM=0;
    }
    public Vehiculos(int a, String b, String c, String d, int f)
    {
        Código=a;
        Marca=b;
        Tipo=c;
        Modelo=d;
        KM=f;
    }

    public int getCódigo() {
        return Código;
    }

    public void setCódigo(int Código) {
        this.Código = Código;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return Marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String Marca) {
        this.Marca = Marca;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return Tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String Tipo) {
        this.Tipo = Tipo;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return Modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String Modelo) {
        this.Modelo = Modelo;
    }

    public int getKM() {
        return KM;
    }

    public void setKM(int KM) {
        this.KM = KM;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "Código=" + Código +
                ", Marca='" + Marca + '\'' +
                ", Tipo='" + Tipo + '\'' +
                ", Modelo='" + Modelo + '\'' +
                ", KM=" + KM;
    }
}
```

Espero haber podido ayudarte. Cualquier duda me dices!

Un Saludo!

Comment: Hola soltek, gracias por su ayuda. Intente hacerlo como me dijiste dejando el array afuera pero no me reconoce el valor inicializado del array. En el for ccm.length y en la impresión de pantalla dice que falta inicializarlo. Al ponerle un null, por defecto tira un error por pantalla antes de ejecutar el for. Y cambiando el ccm.length por la n, ingresan los valores, pero en el momento que ejecuta el constructor para ingresar los valores en el objeto sale otro error. Crei que funcionaria aunque me siento más cerca.

Comment: Hola soltek, gracias por su ayuda. Intente hacerlo como me dijiste dejando el array afuera pero no me reconoce el valor inicializado del array, en el for ccm.length y en la impresión de pantalla sale un error diciendo que falta inicializarlo. Si le pongo un null por defecto, este tira un error por pantalla antes de ejecutar el for. Y cambiando el ccm.length por la n, ingresan los valores, pero en el momento que ejecuta el constructor para ingresar los valores en el objeto sale otro error. Crei que funcionaria aunque me siento más cerca.

Comment: Espero haber solucionado tu problema, si tienes dudar ya sabes! :P

Answer (score 1):

El código tiene un error de sintaxis. Tienes un else después de un for. El código del case 2 debiese quedar así:

```
case 2:{
Vehículos ccm[] = new Vehículos[n];   
if (inte>0){
    System.out.println("***********************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("********                           VEHÍCULOS                               ********");
    System.out.println("***********************************************************************************");
    for(int i=0;i<ccm.length;i++){
        System.out.println("*"+ccm[i].getCódigo()+"*"+ccm[i].getMarca()+"*"+ccm[i].getTipo()+"*"+ccm[i].getModelo()+"*"+ccm[i].getKM()+"*");
    }
}else {
    System.out.println("No tiene registros aún");
}

break;}
```

Te aconsejo mejorar tu indentación. Eso ayuda mucho. Además deja el arreglo arriba, fuera del switch (Vehículos ccm[] = new Vehículos[n];) ya que de esa forma, serán visibles por ambos cases. De la forma como la tienes, estas creando un arreglo vacío en el case 2, por esa razón muestra nada. Saludos!.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda prez, seguire tu consejo de la indentación, ya que fue error mio tener el else sin haber cerrado el if. Creó que es un gran error en la presentación ya que en el código si esta correcto pero al detallar el problema me he confundido. En la parte de la sugerencia al declarar en arreglo arriba del switch, he intentado esto pero no me entra al for para ingresar los datos. simplemente salta al mensaje de finalizar el programa, me gustaría saber si puedo llamar el vector en el segundo case, con el valor modificado de la variable n ingresada por pantalla.